# i am getting an error while inserting data in database by creating Class File in Asp.Net for Database Manipulations

Tags: asp.net

> error :: The parameterized query '(@CustomerName
>   varchar(50),@CustomerGender varchar(50),@Customer' expects the
>   parameter '@CustomerName', which was not supplied. Statement(s) could
>   not be prepared.

my code of .cs file is:

```
public class CustomerCls
{

    private int custid;
    public int CustomerId
    {
        set { custid = value; }
        get { return custid; }

    }

    private string custname;
    public string CustomerName
    {
        set { custname = value; }
        get { return custname; }

    }

    private string gender;
    public string CustomerGender
    {
        set { gender = value; }
        get { return gender; }

    }

    private string city;
    public string CustomerCity
    {
        set { city = value; }
        get { return city; }

    }

    private string strcon;
    public CustomerCls()
    {
        strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbcon"].ConnectionString;
    }

    public void InsertCustomer()
    {
        string sql = "Insert Into Customer(Cust_Name,Cust_Gender,Cust_City) " + " VALUES(@CustomerName,@CustomerGender,@CustomerCity)";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerName", SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value = CustomerName;
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerGender", SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value = CustomerGender;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerCity", SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value = CustomerCity; 

        cmd.Prepare();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();


    }

}
```

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the CustomerCls object calling the InsertCustomer() method has the necessary properties set in code before the call to the method is made:

```
 CustomerCls oCustomerCls = new CustomerCls();
 oCustomerCls.CustomerName = "John Doe";
 // etc...
 oCustomerCls.InsertCustomer();
```

Comment: i already tried this piece of code  here is my code  
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CustomerCls insertobject = new CustomerCls();
            insertobject.CustomerName = TextBox1.Text;
            insertobject.CustomerGender = TextBox2.Text;
            insertobject.CustomerCity = TextBox3.Text;
            insertobject.InsertCustomer();
            
        }

Comment: Since i don't see a constructor assigning the values to your newly-created object, I would suggest you create one to do that...or, alternately, put a breakpoint in your code so that you can see that there is indeed a value being set to CustomerName from TextBox1.Text and so on.

Comment: Like so:  public CustomerCls(string name, string gender, string city)
    {
        strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbcon"].ConnectionString;
  custname = name;
  gender = gender;
  city = city;  
    }

 CustomerCls insertobject = new CustomerCls(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text);   If the creation fails, at least you will get an error that will tell you that one of those values supplied is not correct, or some such.  If all of this doesn't change the error, then I  would suspect that the SqlParameter object on your SqlCommand object is not creating correctly.

Comment: thanku so much @brinky
its working using overloaded constructor.. m new so i would like to ask u, is there any other way to do so using my code..

Comment: The only other thing I might suggest is to add in object creation for your SqlCommand: 
            cmd.Parameters = new SqlParameterCollection();

Comment: Okay, a way to make it slightly cleaner and get rid of the overloaded constructor - Remove all of the private fields that are used as setters for your public properties.  That way, you can assign the TextBox.Text values directly to your object's Public properties in the code behind (which is what it looks like you're already doing), and not have to worry about an unassigned private field not being assigned to, which seemed to be the problem.

Comment: You can just have the public properties like so:   public string CustomerName  {get; set;}

Comment: i used that and that's working. when i using my above mentioned code by creating breakpoints it shows the null value.

Comment: If this is an acceptable answer for your question, would you please mark it as answer?  Thank you!

Comment: You are very welcome!  Feel free to PM me if you have other questions.

Comment: hi @brinky..
i need a favour from ur side.. actually i m stuck in a point. i've never use or create something like progress bar.. and i've a requirement that my senior give me an xml file and i have to implement to that in my database using stord procedure and while importing the xml data into the database he ask to show a progress bar that how much data is imported and after completion it shouls show the completed progress bar.. so can you provide me the sample code bcuz i dont have any idea and m very new in development field.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing these lines to

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerName", SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value = CustomerName;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerGender", SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value = CustomerGender;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerCity", SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value = CustomerCity;
```

to

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerName", SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value = custname;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerGender", SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value = gender;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerCity", SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value = city;
```

Comment: How this would make a difference?

Comment: From the code, I'm not sure if the getter/setter are working. So I simply ask him to try this to see if he is able to get the values. Please feel free to edit or suggest new answers if you have clearer idea why the query did not work.

Comment: @isabellHM  its working but i dont think this is a solution . if i do so then what the use of get set

Comment: First of all, glad that it works for you. To use the getter/setter  (based on your code), try instantiate CustomerCls to use the get/set